# Reload django template into ajax response

Tags: django, ajax

is it possible to reload a Django template after an ajax call?
This is my code.

script.js

```
$('.test').click(function(){
    var platform = $('#testModal').attr('test-attr');
    $.ajax(
      {
        type:"POST",
        url:"test",
        headers: {
          'X-CSRFToken': TOKEN
        },
        dataType: "json",
        cache : false,
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        data: string,
        success: function(data) {
          location.reload();
        }
      });
  });
```

view.py

```
return render(request, "user_interface/index.html", {'my_var': 'abc', 'my_var_2': 'cde'})
```

I tried to use `return HttpResponse(json.dump({'res': 'Ok', 'err': None}), content_type = "application/json")` but when i reload the page it fails.

Comment: How is the page failing exactly? Are you presented with an error message? Or is the page not reloading at all?

Comment: What error message you are getting ?